# Time Took Variable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Overview: I am trying to create quiz game where someone has to answer questions in a certain amount of time. They have 10 seconds to solve each question or it will move to the next controller. The problem is that whenever I click next question before the full time is up it keeps counting down to 10. What should happen is it should stop counting time for that question.

So far I have implemented the following code to try to make this work. `var time = 0` and first created a global variable called time. Then I created timer code as following, `var count = 10` `@IBOutlet var countDownLabel: UILabel!`

Then I create a label that will tick down every second until it reaches 0. Code as follows:

```
if(count > 0) {
    countDownLabel.text = String(count)
    count -= 1
    time += 1
}
print (time)

if (count <= 0 ) {
    count = 10
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"NextQuestion1", sender: nil)
}
```

Summary: Everytime count goes down time should go up. Then at the end it will display the time they. I would gladly appreciate some help on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on the next button, you need to invalidate the timer so that it will stop counting.

Say you created your timer in this way

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(YourSegueFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Then when you click on the next button, use the following line of code to stop the timer

```
timer.invalidate()
```

Here is the demo

[image]

Comment: Is there way to say timer.invalidate() when they press the button?

Comment: @josh What do you mean? You can directly call this method in the button click function to stop the timer

Comment: Can you explain how you can call this in button click function? I need to stop the timer if they click they go to the next question.

Comment: @josh Undated my answer with timer stopped in button click action

Comment: Ok Got it! Let me try that. Thanks!